# Scaling two separate y-axis labels ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting two seperate y-axis labels to show the relationship between electricity consumption and temperature. I seem to lose control of the first y-axis. I want this scale to be approximately 0.2 - 0.4. my temperature scale is fine. I want my consumption scale to look like this.

[image]

But after adding the second scale with the same code it changes to this.

[image]

here is my code:

```
ggplot()+   
    geom_line(data=average_total, aes(x=day,y=average_day,col="Consumption"))+
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*50, name = "Temperature [C]"))+
    geom_line(data=temp, aes(x=day, y=day_temp/50, col="Temperature"))+
    scale_color_manual("",values=c("skyblue4","green4"),
                    labels=c("Consumption","Temperature"))+
labs(title = "Yearly average consumption\nand ambient temperature",
       x = "Year day",
       y = "Electricity consumption Kwh")+
theme_linedraw()
```

And my data:

```
day average_day
<dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.3226814
2   0.3248489
3   0.3254643
4   0.3286167
5   0.3281448
6   0.3346636

day day_temp
<dbl>   <dbl>
1   7.49
2   10.82
3   11.41
4   10.79
5   10.66
6   8.61
```

Any ideas on how I can adjust the first y-axis scale without affecting the temperature axis?

Comment: changing the scaling factor shifts consumption up or down, relatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code. In stead of using your original linear transformation, `~.*50`, I have used `~.*200-40`, and corresponding back transformation as `y=(day_temp+40)/200`.  I have also changed your example data to show the ranges of both variables. You may want to adjust those values to fit your real data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

average_total <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                            average_day = c(0.38, 0.25, 0.21, 0.22, 0.38, 0.40))
temp <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   day_temp = c(0.5,20,30,38,25,4))

ggplot()+   
  geom_line(data=average_total, aes(x=day,y=average_day,col="Consumption"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*200-40, name = "Temperature [C]"))+
  geom_line(data=temp, aes(x=day, y=(day_temp+40)/200, col="Temperature"))+
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("skyblue4","green4"),
                     labels=c("Consumption","Temperature"))+
  labs(title = "Yearly average consumption\nand ambient temperature",
       x = "Year day",
       y = "Electricity consumption Kwh")+
  theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First, the data provided does not fully represent the data you've plotted, so the plots will differ.

I believe you are asking how to control the y_axis breakpoints on the primary ( electricity consumption) axis. You can do that by adding `breaks = seq(.25, .35, by = .025)` to your `scale_y_continuous` function call.

```r
library(ggplot2)

average_total <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                            average_day = c(0.3226814, 0.3248489, 0.3254643, 0.3286167, 0.3281448, 0.3346636))
temp <- data.frame(day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   day_temp = c(7.49,10.82,11.41,10.79,10.66,8.61))

# Initial PLot 

ggplot()+   
  geom_line(data=average_total, aes(x=day,y=average_day,col="Consumption"))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*50, name = "Temperature [C]"))+
  geom_line(data=temp, aes(x=day, y=day_temp/50, col="Temperature"))+
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("skyblue4","green4"),
                     labels=c("Consumption","Temperature"))+
  labs(title = "Yearly average consumption\nand ambient temperature",
       x = "Year day",
       y = "Electricity consumption Kwh")+
  theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

```r
# Adjusted Plot

ggplot()+   
  geom_line(data=average_total, aes(x=day,y=average_day,col="Consumption"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(.25, .35, by = .025),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*50, name = "Temperature [C]"))+
  geom_line(data=temp, aes(x=day, y=day_temp/50, col="Temperature"))+
  scale_color_manual("",values=c("skyblue4","green4"),
                     labels=c("Consumption","Temperature"))+
  labs(title = "Yearly average consumption\nand ambient temperature",
       x = "Year day",
       y = "Electricity consumption Kwh")+
  theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Because you are working with two separate y_axis, on different scales, you're either going to a.) have a truncated primary axis (as seen above) or b.) you'll have a full axis (which you can do by setting the limits) but the low-level breakpoint will result in an axis value every .025 units. Which will be very overwhelming.